# Download file from URL that doesn't end with the extension in python

Tags: python, download, request, media

I have a list of URLs to pages that show either an image or a video, but the URLs don't end with the file's extensions.

For example:

- https://example.com/files/01234-jpg.56789/
- https://example.com/files/98765-mp4.43210/

And the HTML media element also directs to the URL, something like:

```
<body><video controls="" autoplay="" name="media"><source src="https://example.com/files/98765-mp4.43210/" type="video/mp4"></video></body>
```

How can I write a pyhton script that will download these files (like how it does when I Right Click+Save Image/Video As...)?

I tried looking at similar questions, but none worked.

I tried the following code:

```
response = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    fileurl = soup.find("a", href=True)["href"]
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        f.write(requests.get(fileurl).content)
```

But it didn't download the file's content, it wrote into the file some HTML code instead.

I also tried this:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(link) as response:
    with open(filename, 'w+b') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(response, f)
```

But I got this error

> urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden